# How to use a Python generator to feed a neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

this is driving me crazy. I can’t manage to make use of a generator in Python with a neural network. I tried working examples and seems to me that generators produce exactly the same output as this.
Does anyone understand what’s wrong with this code?

`quadrigrams = [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0], [11.0,12.0,13.0,14.0], [21.0,22.0,23.0,24.0], [31.0,32.0,33.0,34.0], [41.0,42.0,43.0,44.0]

def generator():
  i=0
  for w0, w1, w2, w3 in quadrigrams:
    i=i+1
    yield [[w0, w1, w2], [w3]]

for item in generator():
  print(item)


from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, SimpleRNN, LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential

max_features = 10000    # Number of words to consider as features
#maxlen = 500            # Cuts off texts after this many words (among the max_features most common words)
batch_size = 32

model = Sequential() 
model.add(Embedding(3, 32)) 
model.add(LSTM(32)) 
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

history = model.fit_generator(generator, epochs=10)`

It returns this error:

```
"Failed to find data adapter that can handle "
    986         "input: {}, {}".format(
--> 987             _type_name(x), _type_name(y)))
    988   elif len(adapter_cls) > 1:
    989     raise RuntimeError
```

I tried different yield combinations:

```
[[w0, w1, w2], [w3]]
[w0, w1, w2], [w3]
[w0, w1, w2], w3
[[w0, w1, w2], w3]
[[[w0, w1, w2], w3]]
```

But it keeps returning the same error

Answer (score 0):

I have only addressed the question about feeding data using a generator by adjusting the shapes. The `lstm` architecture and the data quality are not considered.

```
def generator():
  i=0
  for w0, w1, w2, w3 in quadrigrams:
    i=i+1
    yield tf.reshape(tf.convert_to_tensor([[w0], [w1], [w2]]),(1,3,1)), tf.convert_to_tensor([w3])

for item in generator():
  print(item)


from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(3, 1)))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
print(model.summary())

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    generator,
    output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32),
    output_shapes=((1,3,1),(1,))
)

history = model.fit(ds, epochs=10)

test = np.array([11.0,12.0,13.0])
test = test.reshape((1, 3, 1))

predictSequence = model.predict(test, verbose=1)
print(predictSequence)
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize there was a problem of vertical shape rather than horizontal.

Comment: Is it( the sample ) working for you ? If your question is answered you may 'upvote' or accept. But I am not executing the `lstm` and predicting useful values.